# GraphQL .NET Authentication with JWT does not work

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, jwt

I am implementing a GraphQL API that I'm trying to secure with JWT.

In my Startup.cs I'm implementing

```
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Secret"]))
        };
    });
```

and

```
  app.UseAuthentication();   <---------- Added authentication
  app.UseGraphQL<ToGatherSchema>();
  app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());
```

I tested authentication on one of my file controllers by adding

```
[Authorize]   <---------- Added authentication
public class FilesController : Controller
{
   ...
```

and it works like a charm, but I cannot seem to get it to authenticate my GraphQL endpoint. I can run queries and mutations without a token in http header.

I've seen some people creating a separate controller to handle POST requests to `/graphql` endpoint, but it seems like more of a workaround than a solution.

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question I know, but I stumbled across it having the same problem. I solved it by adding a call to MapGraphQL in UseEndpoints. The RequireAuthorization method ensures that authentication is required for the endpoint.

```
app.UseAuthentication();   <---------- Added authentication
app.UseGraphQL<ToGatherSchema>();
app.UseGraphQLPlayground(new GraphQLPlaygroundOptions());
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapGraphQL<ToGatherSchema>().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

GraphQl API by default works like a middleware, so it's impossible to use the authorize attribute or JWT token for a communication. A separate route is the only one way.
Also, you able to use [UserContext](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/user-context/) but I'm not sure if this solution what you a looking for.